# Указатели и массивы в C++

Tags: c++

Прошу объяснить, в чем разница в следующих листингах:

1)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

2)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int * a = new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    delete [] a;
    return 0;
}
```

Насколько я знал, в первом варианте n должна быть const, и, собственно, код на листинге 1 не должен компилироваться, однако он работает (оттестировано на gcc-c++-4.4.0-mingw32)! Почему?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ни один из стандартов C++, даже C++11, не включает в себя variable length arrays, просто некоторые компиляторы поддерживают их в качестве расширений. Такая же история с типом long long, правда его все-таки включили в C++11.
Чтобы заставить g++ ругаться на такие нестандартные расширения нужно добавить опцию -pedantic:

```
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long long int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    int b[a];
}
$ g++ test.cpp  -pedantic
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:5: warning: ISO C++ 1998 does not support ‘long long’ [-Wlong-long]
test.cpp:6:12: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘b’ [-Wvla]
$ g++ test.cpp  --std=c++0x -pedantic
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:6:12: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘b’ [-Wvla]
```

Answer (score 3):

В первом случае массив размещается в стеке, а во втором в куче (динамической памяти).

Основное отличие в том, что в стеке ограничен размер массива. Так например при n = 100000 программа работает, а при n = 1000000 уже нет (валится). Для кучи возможный размер значительно больше. 250000000 работает, а 500000000 - уже нет.

Собственно у меня  Windows 7 (64-bit), но MinGW 32-разрядный    gcc (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)

Comment: Да, но почему компилятор не ругается?

Comment: потому что в стандарте есть такая фича. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Answer (score 3):

Под рукой черновик стандарта ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N3092, там указано:

> 8.3.4 Arrays [dcl.array]
>
> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> `D1 [ constant-expression_opt ] attribute-speciﬁer_opt`
>
> (...) If the
> constant-expression (5.19) is present,
> it shall be an integral constant
> expression and its value shall be
> greater than zero.

Откуда следует, что это поведение не соответствует стандарту. Возможно, в более поздних версиях стандарта это уже не так.

**UPD:** Проверил по последней версии черновика стандарта, аналогично.

Comment: Может быть gcc не отвечает стандартам, но он широко распространен и работает.

Comment: Нельзя полагаться на такие фичи. Однажды они вполне могут перестать работать, да и с переносимостью кода могут возникнуть проблемы.

Comment: Там написано, что VLA включен в С99. Так что, должно работать на любом компиляторе, поддерживающем этот стандарт. А сейчас, мне кажется, все основные компиляторы С его поддерживают. А вообще-то, эта штука может быть полезной. Спасибо автору вопроса. 

Единственное - в С такие массивы локализуются в стеке, так что их размеры ограничены размером стека. Но это не такая большая проблема, поскольку размеры стека можно изменять run-time (во всяком случае, в юниксах).

Comment: Речь идёт о C++. С++ и С это два разных, но схожих языка, на которые распространяются разные стандарты.

Comment: @AlexeyM, а Вы почитатель творений имени Б. Гейтса ?

Comment: Это не имеет никакого отношения к Microsoft, это открытые международные стандарты. Так или иначе, ни один из компиляторов С++ не поддерживает стандарт полностью.

Answer (score 2):

А действительно - почему? Значит, в современных версиях компиляторов происходит динамическое создание массивов, объявленных как a[x]. Надо копаться в современных спецификациях. Хороший вопрос.

Comment: В g++ и gcc точно работает (и Си и плюсы) (А почему нет ? alloca() и вперед).